# Item to be cited both as article and as incollection in the same entry

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

How can I use Bibdesk to produce the citation of a paper that indicates both the journal in which the paper originally appeared and the book in which it was later reprinted and that I am actually using?

I would like to obtain something like this:
Gibbs, Josiah Willard, Graphical methods in the thermodynamics of fluids, Transactions of the Connecticut Academy, II, pp. 309-342, Apr-May 1873 (repr. in The scientific papers I. Thermodynamics, Longmans, Green, and co., New York 1906).

The problem is now that Bibdesk allows me to either choose the article format or the incollection format but not boht. Is there a way to create or to import a new category?

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two easy ways of dealing with this:

1. Break up the composite entry into two regular ones and cite them both - like "according to Gibbs et al [1] (as reproduced in [2])."
2. Manually edit the `.bbl` file generated by `bibtex`. Do this at the very end, when you are done with all other changes to your document. Then, replace the `\bibliography{myreferences}` at the end of your document with `input{mydoc.bbl}`. Edit the entry in question in that file to your liking.

If you use the second method, make sure not to inadvertently let `bibtex` overwrite your manual edits. To do so, you might rename the `.bbl` file to `mydoc-edited.bbl` and `\input` that file instead.